# Hibernate: Limit result size of child objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hql

I've got a parent entity which has many child objects, most of which are collections. See below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Set<B> setB;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Set<C> setC;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", nullable = false)
    private Set<D> setD;

    // Skipping more collections as they are not needed for the example
    // Standard getters and setters
    
}
```

Now `classes` B, C and D have A_ID and 5 more `String` columns. Please consider them B1,B2,B3,B4,B5 and so on.
I also have a CrudRepository for A

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Long> {
    Optional<A> findById(Long id);
}
```

I want to fetch the complete A object with an id but the other child collections that A have (setB, setC, setD) contains approx thousands of rows for each A_ID. I want to put a filter to fetch only first 100 rows for a given A_ID.
I have tried putting `@Where(clause = "ROWNUM < 101")` on the collections but it does not work as in the query the table name gets prefixed to the ROWNUM.
I also took a look at `Criteria` and `Criterion` but I am unable to find any working solution.
Since there are many collection of `Objects` in the parent class. So using native queries for each object would be too much rework.
Can anyone please help me with this. Do comment if you need more information.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, what it is not clear is the reason you need only 100 rows... are you trying to fix a performance issue?

Comment: Hello @Sixro- Its more of a GUI thing. The users would like only the first 100 objects. And also some of these collections have millions of objects so it wont be possible to display everyone of them. The users agreed

Comment: Thanks Chitransh, unfortunately I cannot help you.
The only solution I know would involve switching from FetchType.EAGER to LAZY and reducing the batch size, loading only the number of child you need... but I think you don't want to have impacts on all other use cases...

Comment: Yeah that wont solve my issue but thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 1):

That's not so easy. You would have to fetch the collections manually or use a library like [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) on top that supports this out of the box. Also see here for a similar question: [Hibernate - Limit size of nested collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61711226/hibernate-limit-size-of-nested-collection/61769119#61769119)

In your particular case, this could look like the following:

```
@EntityView(A.class)
public interface ADto {

    @IdMapping
    long getId();

    @Limit(limit = "100", order = "id asc")
    Set<BDto> getSetB();

    @Limit(limit = "100", order = "id asc")
    Set<C> getSetC();

    @Limit(limit = "100", order = "id asc")
    Set<D> getSetD();
    
}
```

Comment: Apologies for replying late. Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately I wont be able to use this library because of certain restrictions, but looking at the reference question I get what I want, I have not used this but I will certainly look at some reference material.
Thank you so much for your time

Comment: I tried talking to management but we cannot get a library to do this for us. But is there any way to omit say some collections and then we can fetch it with native queries

Comment: No there is no other way to do this without Blaze-Persistence. You would have to fetch the collections individually and stuff them into a DTO.